# On which points on the x-axis is the function differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The function is

$h(t)=|1+t|+(1+3t^2)^{19}$.

The answer says it's differentiable everywhere except $t=-1$.
If [plotted in WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=h%28t%29%3Dabs%281%2Bt%29%2B%281%2B3t%5E2%29%5E19), h(t) is smooth and is defined at $t=-1$. My question: Why does the answer say it's not differentiable at $t=-1$?

To try solving it, I've computed the derivative to be

$h'(t)=\frac{1+t}{|1+t|}+144t(1+3t^2)^{18}$.

We see an  absolute value in the derivative, so we split it into cases

for $t>-1 \; \; h'(t) = -1+144t(1+3t^2)^{18}$

and

for $t>-1 \; \; h'(t) = 1+144t(1+3t^2)^{18}$.

I think I can see from that that if t approaches -1 from both directions, it is evident that the left and right hand limit will not be the same value, due to the 1 and -1, hence not differentiable in this point. Is this correct thinking? But why was I able to draw a smooth graph for h(t) that is defined in -1?

Comment: How do you "see" that a function is smooth?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski It's smooth by definition since the function is made of elementary functions? I plotted it in WA also, and it's smooth, see the link in the beginning. Looking at the graph again, I noticed the Y axis being large dimensions, perhaps it's fooling me...

Comment: The absolute value function is not considered an elementary function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have theorems about which functions are differentiable, the simplest approach is probably to use the fact that the functions $f$ given by $f(t) = (1 + 3 t^2)^{19}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$. Then, if $h$ were differentiable at $-1$, this would imply that $h - f$ were differentiable at $-1$, but $(h - f)(t) = \lvert t + 1\rvert$. It thus suffices to show that this is not the case, which should be a straightforward application of the definition.